# How to delete a view in Jenkins and automatically its jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

With `Jenkins`, if I delete a view, I want to delete the view's jobs also.

Is there a way to do it properly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Before* deleting your view: in "Manage Jenkins"->"Script Console", run this script:

```
Jenkins.instance.getView("MyView").items.each { item ->
    println "deleting $item.name"
    item.delete()
}
```

After that, the view will be empty -- delete it then.